# Best way to secure a Windows VPS

Tags: windows, firewall, vps

I plan to run a web server on a Windows VPS. I want to secure the machine with a firewall, and I thought to open only ports 80 and 3389 (to connect with RDP). Is this a good choice? And what do you suggest as a simple firewall software for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Firewall is fine for this.

If you will be accessing the server via RDP from a static IP, you should limit 3389 to just that IP. If not, you should make sure to use a very complex password. RDP open to the world attracts a lot of brute force attempts.

Comment: I'll note that you should be very careful limiting to a specific IP for the port if you are on a dynamic IP at home. Not a big issue if your host provides a management interface to take control of the VPS, though.

Comment: @nullity Which is why I said "**If you will be accessing the server via RDP from a static IP,** you should limit 3389 to just that IP."

Comment: Yar of course; I just picked yours out of the two suggestions to really reinforce it! :)

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to windows firewall you should also set up IPSEC rules to deny access to all except your IP or IP blocks to 3389.  You should also implement the [Microsoft SCM guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=16776) for web server security.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to throw in one additional bit of advice:

If you're going to use Remote Desktop Services just for administration (you're not actually hosting an application for a client or something), run it on a [non-standard port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759). Most attacks are going to be automated, and running on a non-standard port will help to reduce the noise from automated attacks.